# Scaling label to fit number of lines needed

Tags: swift3, label, xcode8, ios10

In my app, I have a page where admins can create messages to users.  The preview of those messages (two lines) are displayed in a custom tableview cell and a user can select on of the cells to go to a detail view controller that displays the entire message.

As I will never know how short or long the admin message will be, my question is how to make it so that the receiving label on the detail view controller scales only to the number of lines needed.  In addition, if it is very long, will I have to somehow initiate a scroll view as well?

I'm currently using storyboard, but I assume this will have to be done programmatically?